# Add spaces at the end of a line

Tags: sed

Related: [Add at the end of the line with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516343/add-at-the-end-of-the-line-with-sed)

I looked at this question and tried all methods in the top answer; none of them worked. Every time when I try them and then open the file in Notepad++ it shows what I want to add (20 spaces) on a new line.

What I have:

```
word       word     number    [EOL]
```

What I want:

```
word       word     number                       [EOL]
```

What I end up with currently:

```
word       word     number    [EOL]
                  [EOL]
```

`cat -vet` shows the the line ends with

```
 number          ^M$
```

The ^M doesn't print when using cat normally, so I'm guessing that's the issue.

So in short, how do I add spaces to the end of these lines programatically? I can use bash or powershell (would prefer bash).

Comment: Which command do you use that produces the unwanted two-line-result?

Comment: All of the commands in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2516416/3665278 I tried them all

Comment: And they all produce two lines?

Comment: Correct. I had previously done something to some of the files which ended up causing the command to work, but I can't remember now what it was that I did, I've not been able to replicate it

Comment: I would guess it was `dos2unix`? `^M` are Windows line endings. Try running `dos2unix` first and then try one of the commands again.

Comment: Well while I'm positive that's not what I did before (as I've never heard of it...) it did work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^M` indicates that your file has DOS/Windows-style line endings. Run `dos2unix` to convert it and then run one of the commands to append to the line again.

Answer (score 0):

Your file may have DOS-style CR-NL line endings. So, try this sed command that will remove a carriage return (if present) and add the 20 spaces:

```
sed 's/\r\?$/                    /'
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's slow or if it's waiting for input, but after entering that command it just hangs. If I add *.dat to the end of it it doesn't do anything. Adding *.dat and the -i flag and it does the right thing