# append string after pattern match in solaris sed

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, nawk

I have a file which contains the below

```
hosts:      files
ipnodes:    files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
```

I need to append "dns" at the end of only this two lines

```
hosts:      files dns
ipnodes:    files dns
```

Solaris servers, having very limited options in sed
sed -i is not available
looking for a workaround

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add at the end of the line with sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516343/add-at-the-end-of-the-line-with-sed)

Comment: I have edited the question, having more lines in file, need to append the string next to a pattern matching, sed in solaris servers , -i is not available

Comment: then [Add to the end of a line containing a pattern - with sed or awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591744/add-to-the-end-of-a-line-containing-a-pattern-with-sed-or-awk)

Comment: The `-i` option in GNU `sed` is equivalent, roughly, to saving the output of `sed` in a temporary file, and then copying or moving the temporary file back over the original.  The main difference is that `sed` does the copying automatically.

Answer (score 2):

sed without any fancy settings or in place updates would work:

```
sed 's/.*/& dns/' file
```

If you need to make this edit to ONLY lines beginning with lines beginning with hosts and ipnodes, then add a filter to the command:

```
sed -e '/^hosts/ s/.*/& dns/' -e  '/^ipnodes/ s/.*/& dns/' file
```

Note: I am assuming you'll redirect output to a new file, and replace it with the old.

Comment: I have edited the question, having more lines in file, need to append the string next to a pattern matching, sed in solaris servers , -i is not available

Comment: @judi I've updated my answer. And, yes, I understand GNU options are not available on Solaris by default.

Comment: it works thank you very much ----- > **sed -e '/^hosts/ s/.*/& dns/' -e  '/^ipnodes/ s/.*/& dns/' file**

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised how minimal the [Solaris `sed`](http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWaman/hman1/sed.1.html) really is. I would say use `awk` in that case but that seems *broken* as well. My recommendation is to not shell script on Solaris at all. Stop using Solaris and replace it by a reasonable OS if you want to work with shell scripting. Otherwise use a programming language like Python for scripting.

---

**Former Answer:**

The command should look like this:

```
sed 's/^\(hosts\|ipnodes\).*/& dns/' file
```

On Solaris sed the argument to `-i` is mandatory (unlike GNU sed)

```
sed -i '.backup' 's/^\(hosts\|ipnodes\).*/& dns/' file
```

That will create a file `file.backup`. Check `man sed`!

Comment: there is no -i on Solaris. And extended regexes don't work either. See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/sed-1.html#scrolltoc

Comment: Yes, `\|` is a GNU extension to BRE.

Comment: Wow!, I expected it the same as on BSD. Hard to believe that Oracle comes up with such a poor version of sed.